# Finding points near other points using ArcGIS Server 10.2 rest API?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, distance, query, arcgis-rest-api

I'm using ArcGIS server 10.2. I published my point layer in my admin. I'm going to get json file from that points which are within a fixed distance with any  points that I want.

Any idea?